# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -Ac | grep MyProcess | awk '{print $1}'", env, dir) does not work

Tags: java, exec

When I execute command
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -Ac | grep MyProcess | awk '{print $1}'", env, dir) does not work

i am getting ps: illegal argument |

Comment: if i execute it manually in MAC terminal, i get the ID of the process i need

Answer (score 0):

You can't use shell syntax in the exec method.
If you have to do that, I suggest you: write a simple shell script and then call that script